# Scala pattern matching empty elements repetition

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have the following code snapshot with repeatable boilerplate with profusion of underscore:

```
    ...............
    case (a, c) =>
              (a, c.map {
                case (_, aParam, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _) => aParam
              }, 
               c.map {
                case (_, _ , cParam, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _) => cParam
              },
              c.map {
                case (_, _ , dParam, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _) => dParam
              }
   ................
             c.map {
                case (_, _ , _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, eParam) => eParam
              }
```

I would like to replace this boilerplate, but i wouldn't like to use shapeless or another library.

**UPD**

`c` has type List[(Int, String, ......, String)]

Comment: Are you trying to return a tuple like this: (a, aParam, cParam, None, None, ...) ?

Comment: Where is `c` defined?

Comment: Do you need to use pattern matching ? Seems to be you'd be just fine using `b.map(_._2)`.

Comment: @Michael Zajac `c` is list, i updated the post

Comment: @Cyrille Corpet yes, i need to use pattern matching, in my case `c` is list of tuples and i must handle each element of this tuple individually

Comment: @Joe of course no, return type is not important, returning type looks like (a, aParam, bParam ..... gParam)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get how pattern matching will allow you to handle case more individually than simple lambdas. If you need to refine your pattern matching on one of the elements of the tuple, you can always do something like `c.map(_._3).map{case <some pattern> => <some extracted value>}`.

Comment: @Cyrille Corpet i don't need for the advice about regard improving logic of this code with `map`, my question is related to reducing mentioned boilerplate, pattern matching is necessary here, trust me.

Answer (score 0):

You could clean your code a little with the following:

```
case (a, c) =>
    c.map{
        case (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11) =>
         // do whatever processing you like here for each value in the tuple above
        c2.filter(_.equals(aParam)).doStuff
        ...
    }
```

Comment: you are confusing  - `c` is the list of the tuples (not list of 11 elements), your code is not valid regard my question

Comment: what you're looking for is probably `val (c1, ..., c11) = c.unzip11` if such a method existed (it only exists for 2 and 3).

Answer (score 0):

```
case (a, c) =>
  (a, c.map(_._2).map {
    case aParam => aParam
  }, c.map(_._3).map {
    case cParam => cParam
  }, c.map(_._2).map {
    case dParam => dParam
  }, ..., c.map(_._11).map {
    case eParam => eParam
  })
```

This does exactly the same as your code, although I'm not sure about what `aParam`, `cParam` and others exactly are.

Comment: I have idea to use something like this, but using `_._1 _._2 etc.` is awful, because it is "clean code vice versa" because it's not informative (it will repetitive range `_._1` to `_._11`) - it's not appropriate for our code standard

Comment: If you want to iterate on the elements of your tuple, you can use @Ra Ka's solution, but in my opinion, it means you should not be having tuples, but some other kind of data structure, such as a fixed size list of string. Tuples usually have different type on each of their components, so they cannot be iterated on without some loss of type info. They really are equivalent to case classes without any label on their properties. If you do not like the `._1`, you can always use that equivalence and replace the tuples by case classes.

Comment: I don't need to iterate through elements of tuple, i need to pick up only specific to business logic elements of the tuple and other elements are excessive, as result, i have a profusion of the underscores

Comment: If the different elements of your tuple have specific business meaning, it is probably better to put them in a case class, rather than a tuple, so that you can get what they really are more easily. If you do so, it won't seems so repetitive when you do the equivalent of `.map(_._2)` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You may want something like this:

```
  //########################################################
  //Old Way (If i understand ur approach correctly)
  val tup1 = (7, "apple", "ball", "Cat", "dog")
  val tup2 = (8, "w", "x", "y", "z")
  val tup3 = (9, "r1", "r2", "r3", "r4")

  var tupList: List[(Int, String, String, String, String)] = List(tup1, tup2, tup3)

  tupList.foreach(item => {
    item match {
      case (_, "apple", _, _, _) => println("apple")
      case (_, _, "x", _, _) => println("y")
      case (_, _, _, _, "r4") => println("r4")
    }
  })

  //#######################################################
  //New Way ~
  //Define your match filter like this: (key - position(0 based index)), ("apple", 1) ~ case (_, "apple", _, _, _) 
  val filter: List[(String, Int)] = List(("apple", 1), ("x", 2), ("r4", 4))

  //Now, iterate through list, convert each tuple to iterator, and check each item of tuple with
  //filter condition, i.e. item must match filter string and index e.g. ("apple", 1)
  //Also, you don't have to worry about size of list or tuple. You can create some generic method as well using this logic. 
  tupList.map(tup => {
    val iterator = tup.productIterator
    var i = 0
    while (iterator.hasNext) {
      val item = iterator.next()
      filter.map(f => {
        val filterString = f._1
        val position = f._2
        if (i == position && item == filterString) {
          println(tup) //matched.
        }
      })
      i = i + 1
    }
  })
```